# In IOS App use a png image as pinpad

Tags: ios, authentication, uiimageview, passwords

I have in a uiimageview a png pinpad with Numbers from 0 to 9, clear and enter button. It must react to taps to get the number value, clear the password field or send the password, depending where I tap. How can I do that? If someten could send me an example it would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a collection view with a 3 x 4 grid, or whatever suits your needs. Break up your image and ensure that you have images that will work across all the devices you intend to support and place one image in each cell. Then just rely on standard UICollectionViewDelegate methods to handle user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I only have one image that I get from a service as a png not multiple images. I don't known how to do it as you say.

Thanks anyway for try to give me a solution.